# Jest test of function that contain an async call to User.findAll [sequelize postgresql] fails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs

I’m trying to add a test to `getAllUsers` function but I don’t know why the test is failing?
I think that the assertions are run before all the async call to User.findAllfinishes!!!
do you have any suggestions?
[image: this is result of the test]

this is the file being tested:

```js
const { Op } = require('sequelize')
const { User } = require('../models')
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync')
const AppError = require('../utils/appError')

exports.getAllUsers = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const users = await User.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'username', 'email', 'role', 'avatar'],
    where: {
      id: { [Op.gt]: 0 }
    }
  })
  if (!users.length) {
    return next(new AppError('no data found', 204))
  }
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: users
  })
})
```

and this is the test code:

```js
const userController = require('../controllers/userController')

describe('UserController', () => {
  const users = [
    {
      username: 'Admin',
      role: 'admin',
      avatar: 'bb',
      email: 'admin@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      username: 'User',
      role: 'user',
      avatar: 'bb',
      email: 'user@gmail.com'
    }
  ]
  test('Expect to respond with 200 code and users data', async () => {
    const req = {}
    const res = { status: jest.fn(() => res), json: jest.fn(() => res) }
    const next = jest.fn()
    await userController.getAllUsers(req, res, next) 
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200)
    expect(res.json).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(res.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      status: 'success',
      data: users
    })
  })
})
```

thanks for the help

Comment: The code and test seem good. Maybe it's taken the `if (!users.length)` path, please check that. I'd recommend mocking `User.findAll` from `'../models'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Considering there's no pre-requisite (mocked database) that hasn't been shared in the question

When you run `jest --coverage` it will generate you a coverage report which would give you an overview of the code execution

[image]

above you can see that the if statement has not been executed, meaning that an error is thrown from `User.findAll`

**To solve this:** you can mock the `User` model and it's `findAll`'s resolved value to overcome this

```
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');
const { User } = require('../models');

// generate auto-mock of the module
jest.mock('../models');

describe('UserController', () => {
  const users = [
    // .... same as in the question
  ];
  beforeAll(() => {
    // give the mock function a value
    // for the promise to be resolved with
    User.findAll.mockResolvedValue(users);
  });

  test('Expect to respond with 200 code and users data', async () => {
    // .... same as in the question
  });
});
```